# SQL - sum of every combination

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with 3 columns : A, B and C. These columns can be true or false.
I want to get count of every possible combination.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `A` mediumint default NULL,
  `B` mediumint default NULL,
  `C` mediumint default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (0,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(0,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (1,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,1),(1,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (1,1,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (0,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,0,1),(0,0,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (1,1,1),(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,0,0),(1,1,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (1,1,1),(0,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (0,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,0),(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (0,1,1),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,0,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,0);
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`A`,`B`,`C`) VALUES (1,1,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(1,0,0);
```

Example result (from sample data):

**combination: count**

none: 11
A: 12
B: 17
C: 10
AB: 16
BC: 9
AC: 11
ABC: 14

Is this possible in one query? (MySQL)

Comment: Add the table with sample data

Comment: Is this every combination where those columns are `true`?  i.e. as you have 1 combo ABC, but in reality there could be 8 combos for that group (all three true, all three false, only A true, only B true, only C true, only A false, only B false, only C false).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a simple `count` and `Group by`.

```
SELECT A, B, C, count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B, C;
```

[DEMO:](http://rextester.com/KYEAT23991)

If you want you can show the string of values combined use concat and case...

```
SELECT concat(case when A = 1 then 'A' else '' end, 
              case when B = 1 then 'B' else '' end, 
              case when C = 1 then 'C' else '' end)  as Combination
     , count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B, C
ORDER BY Combination;
```

or as Paul Spiegel shows in comments:

```
SELECT concat(left('A', A), left('B', B), left('C', C)) as Combination
     , count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B, C
ORDER BY Combination;
```

Giving us:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
|    | Combination | count(*) |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 |             |       11 |
|  2 | A           |       12 |
|  3 | AB          |       16 |
|  4 | ABC         |       14 |
|  5 | AC          |       11 |
|  6 | B           |       17 |
|  7 | BC          |        9 |
|  8 | C           |       10 |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: what is the deal with the table name?

Comment: I use the SO Question number so I don't overwrite other tables in rextester.  Just a pattern I follow.  I try to change them when I copy back; but sometimes I forget :P  I don't like stomping on other peoples tables and I've found that using the SO with # seems to keep me out of their hair and them out of mine.  
Select * from `order`; on rextester is someone elses data and I don't like to destroy it.  So I use SO#########_ORDER

Comment: Nice one! Here is a trick to get it shorter: `concat(left('A', A), left('B', B), left('C', C))`

Comment: Ah I get it since the A,B,C is binary it's left of 1 or 0.  Didn't think of that neat! and since left returns z 0 length string.... no need to use such an ugly case statement :P

Comment: Maybe `repeat('A', A)` would be more intuitive. But that are 2*3 more bytes of code ;-). However  - I think it's worth to note that if you add one more column (`D`) you will need one more expression (doesn't matter if `case`, `left` or `repeat`), while other solutions will have to hardcode double as much combinations (2^4=16). With 10 columns you will have 10 expressions and they will cover 1024 combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your combinations are where those columns' values are `TRUE`, you're just looking at a `group by` over those 3 columns.  The `case` logic is just there to present the combo in a single column; you could easily replace "`case`...`end`" with "`A, B, C`" to get the same result with those columns showing their values separately.

```
select 
case 
    when A = 1 and B = 1 and C = 1  then 'ABC'
    when A = 1 and B = 1 and C = 0 then 'AB'
    when A = 1 and B = 0 and C = 1 then 'AC'
    when A = 0 and B = 1 and C = 1 then 'BC'
    when A = 1 and B = 0 and C = 0 then 'A'
    when A = 0 and B = 1 and C = 0 then 'B'
    when A = 0 and B = 0 and C = 1 then 'C'
    else 'oops, this should not happen'
end as `Combo`
--, sum(sumThing) as `sum` --amended to count per question edit
, count(*) as `count`
from myTable
where A = true
or B = true
or C = true
group by A, B, C
```

Comment: what is `sumThing`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Before the question was edited the request was for a `sum` column; but there was no defintion of which column that was over; so `sumthing` is the something to be summed.  That said, the question now asks for a `count`, so I'll amend the answer / remove my punthing.

Comment: didn't handle the 0,0,0 case.

Comment: just remove the where

Comment: @xQbert that's deliberate based on the original question; but as @isaace says, it's easily catered for by removing the where statement & adding another `when` statement (or making use of the `else` to cover this scenario).

Comment: MySQL allows you to compare tuples. So instead of `when A = 1 and B = 1 and C = 1  then 'ABC'` you could write `when (A,B,C) = (1,1,1) then 'ABC'`.  Even better would be `case (A,B,C) when (1,1,1) then 'ABC' when (1,1,0) then 'AB' ...`. But MySQL doesn't like it (though it works for PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple subquery for each combination and union them:

```
SELECT "none", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 0 AND B = 0 AND C = 0
UNION
SELECT "A", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 0 AND C = 0
UNION
SELECT "B", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 0 AND B = 1 AND C = 0
UNION
SELECT "C", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 0 AND B = 0 AND C = 1
UNION
SELECT "AB", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1 AND C = 0
UNION
SELECT "BC", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 0 AND B = 1 AND C = 1
UNION
SELECT "AC", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 0 AND C = 1
UNION
SELECT "ABC", COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1 AND C = 1
```

Comment: @xQbert So? You have lots of concatenations and `left`s :-). It is similar to Juan's answer, but presents vertically as requested by OP. It is Easier to read and understand than yours, but your last one with Paul's suggestion is really cool. Thanks for the +1 ;-) and earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional count

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A=1 THEN 1 END) AS A,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN B=1 THEN 1 END) AS B,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C=1 THEN 1 END) AS C,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A=1 AND B=1 THEN 1 END) AS AB,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A=1 AND C=1 THEN 1 END) AS AC,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN B=1 AND C=1 THEN 1 END) AS BC,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A=1 AND B=1 AND C=1 THEN 1 END) AS ABC,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN A<>1 AND B<>1 AND C<>1 THEN 1 END) AS None
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Presents Horizontally instead of vertically but it works :P